# wordpress bug: Icon appear only when I'm logged in

Tags: wordpress, icons, development-environment, production-environment

I migrated My wordpress site from dev sub-domain to prod domain, everything was work good, but in the prod domain icons won't appear only when I logged in as administrator ! the theme I work with use fontawesome icons !

who can explain and help to solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to flush the permalinks? https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/